# Create child objects from within the parent?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, extends

How can I create child objects from within the parent?

```
class Section
{
    protected $url;
    function __construct($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function createElements()
    {

    } 
}

class ElementA extends Section
{

}

class ElementB extends Section
{

}
```

Each section will contain multiple elements, however, the whole purpose of the section class, is to create the elements, not just store data relating to the section.

Comment: Can you give me more information, Tell me what output you do want?

Comment: I am making a CMS. The section class is for sections such as, `header`, `footer`, `left column` ect. The variable `$url` is a path on the server where the elements are stored for the section. The element classes are for elements, such as `H2`, `P`, 'FORM', and many many others. Currently, the elements are produced from within a static function that takes `$url` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it just like this:

```
public function createElements()
{
    $this->children[] = new ElementA($this->url);      // use $this->url
    $this->children[] = new ElementB('http://www.google.com'); // or not
}
```

Comment: I'm hoping to have only one instance of the Section class for all the elements within the section, otherwise it kind of defeats the purpose of having a Section class. I don't think that it's even possible, but if there is, it would certainly result in much more efficient code.